# Use sed to remove lines that do not match a pattern but keep header line

Tags: sed

I am cleaning up a dataset (csv dataset). I only want to consider registers in which all fields are complete and have the right type of values. This is what I tried:

```
sed -r '{
       /regex_pattern/!d
       more commands follow...
}' $1
```

The program works just fine and does what it is supposed to do. The problem is that it also removes the very first line (header line) since it does not match the specific regex_pattern. I know there is a way to specify the range in which the command should apply so for example:

```
sed '2,$ s/A/a/'
```

will do substitutions on data skipping the header line. Based on this logic I tried:

```
sed -r '{
       2,$/regex_pattern/!d
       more commands follow...
}' $1
```

so that the header line will be untouched however this code does not run at all.So what (and why) would be the right command to do what I am intending?

As an example, imagine my csv file is fruits.csv and that my regex_pattern is [0-9]+,[0-9]+

```
apples,oranges
20,5
7,3
,4
a,b
12,22
```

When I call the .sh script that contains the sed commands in should output:

```
apples,oranges
20,5
7,3
12,22
```

So, note that:

1. Header line was not deleted even though it does not match the regex_pattern.
2. Line number 4, i.e. ",4" was deleted as it does not match the regex_pattern.
3. Line number 5, i.e. "a,b" was deleted as it does not match the regex_pattern.

Any help is very much appreciated and I wish to thank you all in advance.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it like this, matching the whole line, starting at the second line:

```
sed -r '
2,${/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/!d}
' file
```

Output

```
apples,oranges
20,5
7,3
12,22
```

---

If you also want to allow single numbers or more than just 2 comma separated numbers:

```
sed -r '
2,${/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/!d}
' file
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware I needed to put first the range and then the command enclosed in between {}. I find it strange that when it comes to substitution instead of deletion the {} are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '2,${/[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+/!d}' input_file
apples,oranges
20,5
7,3
12,22
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware I needed to put first the range and then the command enclosed in between {}. I find it strange that when it comes to substitution instead of deletion the {} are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

any one of these should work in `gawk`, `mawk1/2`, or `macos nawk`

```
mawk 'NF-_^(NF==NR)' FS='^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$'
nawk '(NF!=NR)!=NF'  FS='^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$'
gawk  'NF-(NF!~NR)'  FS='^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$'
```

'

```
apples,oranges
20,5
7,3
12,22
```

more concisely would be

```
mawk -F'[0-9]+,[0-9]+' '(NF<NR)-NF' #     using FS

gawk  '/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/^+(NF<NR)'    # not using FS
nawk  '(NF<NR)<=/([0-9]+,?){2}/'    # same approach, rev. order

mawk '(NF~NR)-/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/'      # truly fringe but 
                                    # concise syntax
nawk '(NF~NR)!=/([0-9]+,?){2}/'     # same approach, to 
                                    # circumvent nawk peculiarities
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is a bad choice for working with CSVs since it doesn't have any inbuilt functionality for working with fields, nor literal strings, nor variables, doesn't use EREs by default (all of the answers you have so far will only work with GNU sed), etc. To do what you specifically want with any awk in any shell on every Unix box is simply:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || /[0-9]+,[0-9]+/' file
apples,oranges
20,5
7,3
12,22
```

which says "if the current line number (stored in `NR`) is 1 or the regexp matches the current line contents then print the line". Anything else you want to do with your CSV will also be easier with awk than with sed.

Answer (score 0):

Meh, I would just preserve first line.

```
sed -r '
   1{p;d}
   /regex_pattern/!d
   more commands follow...
' "$1"
```

or run it not for first line:

```
1!{
   /regex_pattern/!d
   more commands follow...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1!{/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/!d}' file
```

If it is not the first line, delete any line that does not match one set of comma separated natural numbers.

Alternative:

```
sed -E '1b;/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/!d' file
```

Or:

```
sed -nE '1p;1b;/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/p' file
```